# Multiplicity error in one to Many Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have multiple entities nested together and when I try and Add the survey class I get the error

> Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Response_Pages_Source' of the relationship 'SurveyMonkeyAPIv3.Response_Pages' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.

Since they both inherit Entity

```
public abstract class Entity  :IEquatable<Entity>
{

    [DataMember]
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Convert.ToInt16(Id);
    }

    public bool Equals(Entity other)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Survey Entity

```
public class Survey : Entity, IEquatable<Survey>
{
//More fields//
    [DataMember]
    public string AnalyzeUrl { get; set; }


    [DataMember]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public override long Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Language { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int? PageCount { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual List<Page> Pages { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Preview { get; set; }
    //More Fields
    public bool Equals(Survey other)
    {
        return this.Id == other.Id;
    }
}
```

and Page

```
public class Page : Entity, IEquatable<Page>
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public new long? Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int? Position { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int? QuestionCount { get; set; }
   //More Objects

    // public long SurveyId { get; set; }
    // public List< Survey> Survey   { get; set; }
    //tried including these , can't set in my automappers
```

but I cannot see a way to resolve this issue.

ADDED:

Was pointed to Response Entity , which follows

```
public class Response : Entity, IEquatable<Response>
{
    [DataMember]
    public string AnalyzeUrl { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public CollectionMode? CollectionMode { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public long? CollectorId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string CustomValue { get; set; }

    //[DataMember]
    //public Dictionary<string, string> CustomVariables { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string EditUrl { get; set; }

    [DataMember]

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public new long? Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }

    //[DataMember]
    //public Dictionary<string, object> LogicPath { get; set; }

    //[DataMember]
    //public Dictionary<string, object> Metadata { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual List<object> PagePath { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual List<ResponsePage> Pages { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual List<ResponseQuestion> Questions { get; }

    [DataMember]
    public long? RecipientId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public ResponseStatus? ResponseStatus { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public long? SurveyId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int? TotalTime { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Response other)
    {
        return Id == other.Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: A survey can have many page, but why a Page can have many survey?

Comment: Do you have a Response entity by any chance? It looks like the name of the relationship tells you the problem is between Response and Page entities.

Comment: I do Have a response Entity,  Sorry - will edit

Comment: Page to Survey (many?) it can't that's another error - created in an attempt to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you add in your Page entity the foreign key to Response. I think this will tell us the root of the problem.

Comment: I can't, The ResponsePage object is separate from the Page Object

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with Survey, Your problem is between Response and Page or a table in the middle. Your exception is telling you that and the code you exposed does not show how Page references Response.

Comment: the line from Page to response is
response -> Survey -> Page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the Survey property (from Page) with , actually you need a add a new property:

```
[ForeignKey("SurveyId")]
[DataMember]
public Survey Survey {get;set;}
```

And the list of pages from Survey with:

```
 [InverseProperty(nameof(Page.Survey))]
```

Comment: I think I understand the foreign Key but the can you explain the inverse property?

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Do I need [ForeignKey("SurveyID")] public long SurveyID

Comment: You need public long SurveyID (without the foreignkey attribute), but you also need the navigation property described by me above (the object itsself): public Survey Survey {get;set;} (with the foreign key on it)

Comment: Thanks that worked. Sorry I didn't mark it sooner, I had other issues and wasen't sure I had it right